# Symfony2, missing controller's first letter from a config routes

Tags: symfony

I'm getting a weird error in console after the command 'route:debug'.

```
`
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException] 
Cannot import resource "....../src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
from "....../app/config/routing.yml". 
(Class could not be determined for Controller identified by 
"Acme\MyBundle\Controller \ ageController"
`
```

where in Acme/MyBundle/config/routes.yml I have

```
resource: "Acme\MyBundle\Controller\PageController"
```

linked from app/config/routing.yml

```
resource: "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```

By examining the code it seems that for some reason `Yaml::parse($path)` returns in `$config['resource']` the controller name as "ageController", without the "P" letter

...Where am I so wrong?

Many thanks

--------EDIT-------

Thanks for the useful response from @piotrekkr.

By escaping "P" char, it works. thanks Piottekr

So it became:

`Acme\MyBundle\Controller\\PageController`

Comment: You sure there is no broken encoding inside your yaml? This part `"Controller \ "` inside `"Acme\MyBundle\Controller \ ageController"` looks suspicious. Can you open this file in some editor that is utf-8 compatible and check if it is ok?

Comment: I'm using Sublime text, I think it's ok. It's weird that if I change the resource string in  CageController or SageController or whatever, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is that `\P` is special character in YAML. From http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092

> 5.7. Escaped Characters
>
> All non-printable characters must be escaped. YAML escape sequences
>   use the “\” notation common to most modern computer languages. Each
>   escape sequence must be parsed into the appropriate Unicode character.
>   The original escape sequence is a presentation detail and must not be
>   used to convey content information.
>
> Note that escape sequences are only interpreted in double-quoted
>   scalars. In all other scalar styles, the “\” character has no special
>   meaning and non-printable characters are not available.

And the character

> [58]  ns-esc-paragraph-separator ::= “P” - Escaped Unicode paragraph separator (#x2029) character.

Try using `\\P` in your YAML